# Application going down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a selenium script and the application also runs fine. But in some case all a sudden application goes down and this can happens at any stage of run the script.

So how to handle this because if Application goes down An Error page opens up and in script i may be trying to click a button or verifying something which doesn't happen and throws a exception.

Comment: Describe "goes down", what error page? What are you doing exactly?

Comment: So that's a good thing. This is what might happen when u r live. report it to dev/server/devops team regarding it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like its an application issue. You need to report the issue. Also it looks like you need to improve your infrastructure so that your application can run smoothly.

**No recommaned:** If you need to test it anyway, please add Thread.sleep(2000) after click() to make script execution slow.